# Generic SortedList, How to find the index of the first element that is greater than the search key?

Tags: c#, generics

Without using extensions methods (LINQ). I am restricted to .NET 2.0 unfortunately. (Yeah, it sucks)

Looking for something close to O(log(n)).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: dss539: read the StackOverflow FAQs. They are pretty clear in stating that homework questions are not to be ignored.

Comment: I wish it was homerwork, but no, real work here.

Comment: @TheTXI - Yes, I'm just saying it should have the homework tag is all, if it were homework.

Comment: I am not a big fan of the "homework" tag.  Why should it matter if it is homework or not?  It is a legitimate question.

Comment: @Andrew - People can highlight/filter based on that tag, then. Why would someone want to do that, is the next natural question. Well the person may love answering homework questions because they're often quite easy. Or the person my want to filter then out of their question lists because they know that homework questions can be easily answered by others. Also, it's an interesting statistic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To find the first key that is greater than a given key you could use the list of keys `SortedList<T>.Keys` and perform a [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search) or [Interpolation Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) on the keys. This will yield `O(log(n))` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) states that a key look up is `O(1)`).

Comment: Yes! First Key that greater than the search key or even First key that is less than the search key. Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 2):

Binary search it for an O(n log n) lookup.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search for explanation, though I can't imagine you need it.

Comment: Binary search is O(log(n)) if item access is O(1).

Answer (score 0):

search where things are in oder O(log n) binary search

search for where things are not in order O(n) linear. Can't do better if things are not in order.

The idea of making the values in order by order takes O(n * log(n)) unless you are going to be doing this over and over and caching the result why bother? just use your linear search.

(note thought you were interested in searching the value not the key)