# System.Collections best choice for my scenario

Tags: datetime, collections, fifo

I want a collection for storing two types: `string` and `DateTime`.

The `string` should be the key of my collection and the `DateTime` is the insertion time of it into the collection. I want to remove items from the collection in a `FIFO` manner.

The collection should reject duplicate keys and queryable by `DateTime` so if want to now the number of items older than a given date it could answer.

Comment: Try using a hashtable and a sorted list at the same time. When you add, add to the hashtable first to prevent duplicates, then do a binary search on the time to add into the sorted list. When you search, you can do a binary search and count forwards/backwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no single builtin C# datatype that do all those things with maximal efficiency, mostly as you indicated two things you'd have to lookup by.

That being said, a `Dictionary<string, DateTime>` will be the **simplest solution** that gives you all the features you need, basically out of the box.  However, that collection will give O(n) complexity for the DateTime lookups, and worse-than-O(1) removal time.  That is probably not a big deal, but you didn't describe your performance requirements, the expected sizes of your dataset, or which access types happen most frequently.

To improve on the "older-than-DateTime" lookup performance and the FIFO removal, you could also keep a second index, such as a SortedList.  More memory usage and somewhat-slower overall insertion time but DateTime and removal queries will be faster.  For "older-than-DateTime" you can use a [binary search of the SortedList.Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966649/generic-sortedlist-how-to-find-the-index-of-the-first-element-that-is-greater-th).

Comment: How can you have less-than-constant removal time?!

Comment: @Lambert: Ha, I meant "less-than-O(1)" to mean "worse-than-O(1)" but I guess I didn't properly specify my sort order.  ;)  Edited for clarity, thanks.

Comment: Ohhh haha okay, I didn't get it at first! That was amusing. :)

Comment: No special performance consideration. Also don't need sorting. Just `FIFO` and and query based on `DateTime` are needed.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, DateTime>` should do your trick. It has methods to process the collection as you need.